# Handling exceptions and CTRL+C in python multiprocessing and multithread

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, multiprocessing

My code does the following:

- Starts processes to collect data
- Starts processes to test model
- One thread takes care of aggregating the data to train the model
- One thread aggregates the test results

I need to handle exceptions such that if the training thread fails everything terminates, but if the testing thread fails training continues.

Below is a MWE (there is no model, but how I manage processes and threads is the same).

It works but I cannot catch CTRL+C. If I press it, I get a long text of messages, but the program keeps running.
I have read that I should set the main thread as `daemon = True` but nothing changes. I have tried placing a `try except` around the main call to `run` to no avail.

How can I gracefully end the program with CTRL+C?

And other questions:

- Is there a better way to end the program when the training thread ends? I am using the variable `terminate` since `daemon = True` doesn't work. I have read about using `concurrent.future` but I cannot find a simple guide for that.
- Is it better to use one pool, as in my example, or two (one for the collect processes, one for the training processes)? Would there be any difference?
- How can I make each thread to catch the right exception? My code raises exceptions in `collect` and `test`, which are run by the processes. However, an exception raised by `collect` must be caught by `run_train`, while an exception raised by `test` must be caught by `run_test`.

```
import threading
import logging
import traceback
import torch
import time
from torch import multiprocessing as mp
try:
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
except:
    pass

shandle = logging.StreamHandler()
log = logging.getLogger('rl')
log.propagate = False
log.addHandler(shandle)
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)


def collect(id, queue, data_collect):
    log.info('Collect %i started ...', id)
    try:
        while True:
            idx = queue.get()
            if idx is None:
                break
            data_collect[idx] = torch.rand(1)
            queue.task_done()
            # actually do something meaningful
    except Exception as e:
        log.error('Exception in collect process %i', id)
        traceback.print_exc()
        raise e


def test(id, queue, data_test):
    log.info('Test %i started ...', id)
    try:
        while True:
            idx = queue.get()
            if idx is None:
                break
            data_test[idx] = torch.rand(1)
            queue.task_done()
            # actually do something meaningful
    except Exception as e:
        log.error('Exception in test process %i', id)
        traceback.print_exc()
        raise e


def run():
    steps = 0
    num_collect_procs = 3
    num_test_procs = 2
    max_steps = 10
    terminate = False

    data_collect = torch.zeros(num_collect_procs).share_memory_()
    data_test = torch.zeros(num_test_procs).share_memory_()

    manager = mp.Manager()
    pool = mp.Pool()
    collect_queue = manager.JoinableQueue()
    test_queue = manager.JoinableQueue()

    # Start collection and testing processes
    for i in range(num_collect_procs):
        pool.apply_async(collect, args=(i, collect_queue, data_collect))

    for i in range(num_test_procs):
        pool.apply_async(test, args=(i, test_queue, data_test))

    # Define target function for the learning thread
    def run_train():
        nonlocal steps, terminate
        log.info('Training thread started ...')
        while steps < max_steps and not terminate:
            try:
                for idx in range(num_collect_procs):
                    collect_queue.put(idx)
                collect_queue.join()
                time.sleep(0.1)
                log.info('Training, %i %f', steps, data_collect.sum())
                steps += 1
            except:
                terminate = True
                for idx in range(num_collect_procs):
                    collect_queue.put(None)
                break
        log.info('Training done')


    # Define target function for the testing thread
    def run_test():
        nonlocal steps, terminate
        log.info('Testing thread started ...')
        while steps < max_steps and not terminate:
            try:
                for idx in range(num_test_procs):
                    test_queue.put(idx)
                test_queue.join()
                time.sleep(0.1)
                log.info('Testing, %i %f', steps, data_test.sum())
            except:
                for idx in range(num_test_procs):
                    test_queue.put(None)
                break
        log.info('Testing done')

    learning_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_train, name='train')
    learning_thread.start()

    testing_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_test, name='test')
    testing_thread.start()

    learning_thread.join()
    testing_thread.join()

    collect_queue.join()
    test_queue.join()
    pool.terminate()
    pool.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: Why do you create two locks and then never use either?

Comment: @user2357112 My bad, I copy-pasted it from my code and forgot to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle Ctrl-c interrupts, you need to initialize your pool processes to ignore the interrupt. This is best accomplished using a pool initializer function as in the code below. You didn't specify your platform, but using *spawn* on Linux might still result in a stack trace being printed, but everything should terminate.

Since you are already using a multiprocessing pool, I would get rid of using explicit queues and submit your range of indices using `map_async`, which is non blocking. Because you seem to want a specific number of processes for training and testing, this would necessitate two pools:

```py
import logging
import traceback
import torch
import time
from torch import multiprocessing as mp
from functools import partial
import signal
import sys

try:
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
except:
    pass

shandle = logging.StreamHandler()
log = logging.getLogger('rl')
log.propagate = False
log.addHandler(shandle)
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def init_pool_processes(*args):
    global terminate_event

    terminate_event = args[0]
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN) # Ignore Ctrl-c

def collect(data_collect, idx):
    """
    This now processes a single idx
    """
    if terminate_event.is_set():
        return
    try:
        data_collect[idx] = torch.rand(1)
        # actually do something meaningful
        ...
    except Exception as e:
        log.error('Exception in collect for idx %i', idx)
        traceback.print_exc()
        raise e


def test(data_test, idx):
    """
    This now processes a single idx
    """
    if terminate_event.is_set():
        return
    try:
        data_test[idx] = torch.rand(1)
        # actually do something meaningful
        pass
    except Exception as e:
        log.error('Exception in test process %i', id)
        traceback.print_exc()
        raise e

def run():
    steps = 0
    num_collect_procs = 3
    num_test_procs = 2
    max_steps = 10
    terminate_event = mp.Event()
    completion_event = mp.Event() # Training has been completed

    data_collect = torch.zeros(num_collect_procs).share_memory_()
    data_test = torch.zeros(num_test_procs).share_memory_()

    # Since you want to control the number of processes used for
    # training and collecting, we need two pools:
    collect_pool = mp.Pool(num_collect_procs,
                           initializer=init_pool_processes,
                           initargs=(terminate_event,)
                           )
    test_pool = mp.Pool(num_test_procs,
                        initializer=init_pool_processes,
                        initargs=(terminate_event,)
                        )

    def collect_completion(result):
        nonlocal steps

        if isinstance(result, Exception):
            # Got an exception so do not submit any more tasks
            # and prevent any more tasks from being
            terminate_event.set() # Force termination
            completion_event.set() # Show we are done
        elif steps < max_steps:
            # Submit next collection of indices:
            log.info('Training, %i %f', steps, data_collect.sum())
            collect_pool.map_async(partial(collect, data_collect),
                                   range(num_collect_procs),
                                   callback=collect_completion,
                                   error_callback=collect_completion
                                   )
            time.sleep(.1) # What is this for?
            if steps == 0:
                # kick of test tasks
                test_completion(None)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            steps += 1
        else:
            completion_event.set() # Show we are done

    def test_completion(result):
        nonlocal steps

        if not isinstance(result, Exception) and not terminate_event.is_set() and steps < max_steps:
            # Submit next collection of indices:
            log.info('Testing, %i %f', steps, data_test.sum())
            test_pool.map_async(partial(test, data_test),
                                range(num_test_procs),
                                callback=test_completion,
                                error_callback=test_completion
                                )

    try:
        # Start the ball of rolling:
        collect_completion(None)

        # Wait for collection tasks to complete:
        completion_event.wait()

        # Now it is safe to wait for all submitted tasks to complete:
        collect_pool.close()
        collect_pool.join()
        test_pool.close()
        test_pool.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

**Update**

If you only want to run a test step after a new training step completes, then:

```py
import logging
import traceback
import torch
import time
from torch import multiprocessing as mp
import multiprocessing as mp
from functools import partial
import signal
import sys

try:
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')
except:
    pass

shandle = logging.StreamHandler()
log = logging.getLogger('rl')
log.propagate = False
log.addHandler(shandle)
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def init_pool_processes(*args):
    global terminate_event

    terminate_event = args[0]
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN) # Ignore Ctrl-c

def collect(data_collect, idx):
    """
    This now processes a single idx
    """
    if terminate_event.is_set():
        return
    try:
        data_collect[idx] = torch.rand(1)
        # actually do something meaningful
        ...
    except Exception as e:
        log.error('Exception in collect for idx %i', idx)
        traceback.print_exc()
        raise e


def test(data_test, idx):
    """
    This now processes a single idx
    """
    if terminate_event.is_set():
        return
    try:
        data_test[idx] = torch.rand(1)
        # actually do something meaningful
        pass
    except Exception as e:
        log.error('Exception in test process %i', id)
        traceback.print_exc()
        raise e

def run():
    steps = 0
    num_collect_procs = 3
    num_test_procs = 2
    max_steps = 10
    terminate_event = mp.Event()
    completion_event = mp.Event() # Training has been completed
    stop_tests = False

    data_collect = torch.zeros(num_collect_procs).share_memory_()
    data_test = torch.zeros(num_test_procs).share_memory_()

    # Since you want to control the number of processes used for
    # training and collecting, we need two pools:
    collect_pool = mp.Pool(num_collect_procs,
                           initializer=init_pool_processes,
                           initargs=(terminate_event,)
                           )
    test_pool = mp.Pool(num_test_procs,
                        initializer=init_pool_processes,
                        initargs=(terminate_event,)
                        )

    def submit_next_collection(this_step):
        # Submit next collection of indices:
        log.info('Training, %i %f', steps, data_collect.sum())
        collect_pool.map_async(partial(collect, data_collect),
                               range(num_collect_procs),
                               callback=collect_completion,
                               error_callback=collect_completion
                               )

    def submit_next_test(this_step):
        # Submit next collection of indices:
        log.info('Testing, %i %f', steps, data_test.sum())
        test_pool.map_async(partial(test, data_test),
                            range(num_test_procs),
                            callback=test_completion,
                            error_callback=test_completion
                            )


    def collect_completion(result):
        nonlocal steps

        if isinstance(result, Exception):
            # Got an exception so do not submit any more tasks
            # and prevent any more tasks from being
            terminate_event.set() # Force termination
            completion_event.set() # Show we are done
            return

        if not stop_tests:
            submit_next_test(steps)

        steps += 1
        if steps < max_steps:
            submit_next_collection(steps)
            time.sleep(0.1)
        else:
            completion_event.set() # Show we are done

    def test_completion(result):
        nonlocal stop_tests

        if isinstance(result, Exception):
            # No more testing:
            stop_tests = True

    try:
        # Start the ball of rolling:
        submit_next_collection(0)

        # Wait for collection tasks to complete:
        completion_event.wait()

        # Now it is safe to wait for all submitted tasks to complete:
        collect_pool.close()
        collect_pool.join()
        test_pool.close()
        test_pool.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I have the `time.sleep` otherwise the terminal output is too fast and it is hard to see error messages. And yes, in Ubuntu CTRL+C was actually already working, the problem was on Windows.

Comment: I have 2 questions. I have managed to make it work with `concurrent.future` (see my own answer). Is there any advantage / disadvantage to using it? 
In my original (much bigger) code I also write results from both threads (`run_train` and `run_test`) on a csv file. I use a lock from `threading.Lock()` to prevent concurrent writes. Is this enough? I create a lock at the beginning of the functions, then do `with lock: csv_logger.log(...)` within the loop. So far I haven't had any problem, but I am wondering if it was just luck. 
Thanks again!

Comment: I normally give longer descriptions with my answers, but I had to move on to something else. Note that there is no need for threads and worker functions  `run_test` and `run_train`; everything is accomplished in the callback functions: when the call to `map_async` completes, it submits to the pool the next run (unless there was an exception). So I think this is simpler logic than what you had. In this program don't see a big difference between `multiprocessing.Pool` or `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`.

Comment: If you are doing your file I/O in a callback function, then that function is run to completion before it can be re-entered and so no locking would be required.

Comment: For my example you are right. The thing is that my code does some stuff for which the structure I used in this example was necessary. For instance, I need `collect` and `test` to have a loop because before the loop I instantiate some objects. This takes time and I don't want to do it for every call. So I just create the object once and let `collect` run "forever". 
I am going to see how to adapt your solution, since it runs faster and is more elegant than mine. I am a bit new to multiproc and multithread, so your answer is giving me a lots of idea.

Comment: If you are, however, using two pool as I am using, then each pool's callback could be running concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

I did it using `concurrent.future` and `done_callback` to catch exceptions in processes. The code is longer than I expected, so if anyone has a better solution I'll be happy to use theirs.

The code is below. A few notes if anyone would like to use it:

- I am setting the context to `spawn` because it's the only one supported by Windows, and I need the same code to work on Ubuntu and Windows.
- The exceptions raises by the processes cannot be directly read by the threads. However, if an exception is raised then the `future` object will consider the job as done, so I use `done_callback` to clean the queues and update the `terminate` variable to notify the threads to end.
- Another way to communicate between processes and thread is to read the shared data they use. In this example, I check for `nan`.
- The program ends only if an error happens in `data_collect` or `run_train`. If something fails during testing, training keeps going.
- This also catches `CTRL+C`.
- In my example, `collect` and `train` basically do the same things (assigning random values to a tensor), but this is just an example. In practice they would do different stuff.

```py
import logging
import traceback
import torch
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from torch import multiprocessing as mp

shandle = logging.StreamHandler()
log = logging.getLogger('rl')
log.propagate = False
log.addHandler(shandle)
log.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# to randomly raise errors
# play with them to see how the program behaves
error_prob_collect = 0.
error_prob_test = 0.5
error_prob_training = 0.
error_prob_testing = 0.

def collect(id, queue, data):
    log.info('Collect %i started ...', id)
    while True:
        try:
            idx = queue.get()
            if idx is None:
                break
            data[idx] = torch.rand(1)
            if torch.rand(1) < error_prob_collect:
                data[idx] = torch.nan # the thread will read this
                raise Exception('unlucky training')
        except Exception as e:
            log.error('Exception in collect process %i', id)
            traceback.print_exc()
        finally:
            queue.task_done()
    log.info('Collect %i completed', id)


def test(id, queue, data):
    log.info('Test %i started ...', id)
    while True:
        try:
            idx = queue.get()
            if idx is None:
                break
            data[idx] = torch.rand(1)
            if torch.rand(1) < error_prob_test:
                data[idx] = torch.nan # the thread will read this
                raise Exception('unluckly testing')
        except Exception as e:
            log.error('Exception in test process %i', id)
            traceback.print_exc()
        finally:
            queue.task_done()
    log.info('Test %i completed', id)


def run():
    steps = 0
    terminate = False
    num_collect_procs = 3
    num_test_procs = 2
    max_steps = 10

    data_collect = torch.zeros(num_collect_procs).share_memory_()
    data_test = torch.zeros(num_test_procs).share_memory_()

    ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')
    manager = mp.Manager()
    collect_queue = manager.JoinableQueue()
    test_queue = manager.JoinableQueue()

    collect_pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(num_collect_procs, mp_context=ctx)
    test_pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(num_test_procs, mp_context=ctx)

    def clear_collect(future):
        while not collect_queue.empty():
            try:
                collect_queue.task_done()
            except ValueError:
                break
        nonlocal terminate
        terminate = True

    for i in range(num_collect_procs):
        future = collect_pool.submit(collect, i, collect_queue, data_collect)
        future.add_done_callback(clear_collect)

    for i in range(num_test_procs):
        future = test_pool.submit(test, i, test_queue, data_test)

    def run_train():
        nonlocal steps, terminate
        log.info('Training thread started ...')
        while steps < max_steps:
            try:
                for idx in range(num_collect_procs):
                    collect_queue.put(idx)
                collect_queue.join()
                time.sleep(0.1) # just to make printed output easier to read
                log.info('Training, %i %f', steps, data_collect.sum())
                steps += 1
                if torch.rand(1) < error_prob_training:
                    raise Exception('bad training')
            except:
                log.error('   Error in training thread, we are going to terminate everything')
                traceback.print_exc()
                break
            if data_collect.isnan().any():
                log.error('   Training thread knows that there was an error in data_collect, we are going to terminate everything')
                break
        log.info('Training ended')
        for i in range(num_collect_procs):
            collect_queue.put(None)
        terminate = True

    def run_test():
        nonlocal steps
        log.info('Testing thread started ...')
        while steps < max_steps and not terminate:
            try:
                for idx in range(num_test_procs):
                    test_queue.put(idx)
                test_queue.join()
                time.sleep(0.1) # just to make printed output easier to read
                log.info('Testing, %i %f', steps, data_test.sum())
                if torch.rand(1) < error_prob_testing:
                    raise Exception('bad testing')
            except:
                log.error('   Error in testing thread, but we keep going')
                traceback.print_exc()
            if data_collect.isnan().any():
                log.error('   Testing thread knows that there was an error in data_test, but we keep going')
        log.info('Testing ended')
        for i in range(num_test_procs):
            test_queue.put(None)

    training_thread = ThreadPoolExecutor(1)
    testing_thread = ThreadPoolExecutor(1)
    training_thread.submit(run_train)
    testing_thread.submit(run_test)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: By the way, it is only `run_train` that increments `steps`. So if each iteration of the `while steps < max_steps and not terminate` loop in `run_test` runs more quickly than `steps` is being incremented, it could be executing many iterations of this loop without `steps` changing (this is also true with my answer). Maybe you should only run another iteration of `run_test` whenever an iteration of `run_train` completes (???).

Comment: @Booboo Yes, I have a check on `steps` on my other code: a test step happens only if a train steps have been done, but training doesn't wait for testing (training needs to run as fast as possible in my case). This was just the simplest example I could make to get help on the handling of errors.